# Android 3.3.1 - Add google map markers from room database

Tags: android, android-asynctask, google-maps-markers

I have a fragment; MapViewFragment which displays a google map. I want to add markers to it from my database. If I try to add markers in onMapReady, I get an error that I'm on the main thread. If I try to add markers like below, I get an error that I'm not on the main thread to add markers. How can I get the list AND add markers to the map?

```
   private class InsertMarkersAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

    private InsertMarkersAsyncTask() {
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        //TODO: This needs work
        List<Site> sites = SiteDatabase.getInstance(getContext()).siteDAO().loadSites();
        for (int i = 0; i < sites.size(); i++) {
            String[] siteLatLng = String.valueOf(sites.get(i).getLatlng()).split(",");
            Double[] doubleLatLng = new Double[2];
            doubleLatLng[0] = Double.parseDouble(siteLatLng[0]);
            doubleLatLng[1] = Double.parseDouble(siteLatLng[0]);
            LatLng current = new LatLng(doubleLatLng[0], doubleLatLng[1]);
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(current).title(sites.get(i).getSiteName()));
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {

        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try addMarker in onProgressUpdate() call and either pass in the two vars or make those global since you're using a loop. You also should check to make sure the AsyncTask doesn't block the UI thread at all even if its all in doInBackground(). I've had poor results from ATs in the past where a regular old Thread didn't. I find ATs are crap.

Comment: @CmosBattery Thanks, that did it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up with.

I called the AsyncTask here...

```
    new InsertMarkersAsyncTask().execute();
```

Async set up here...

```
    private class InsertMarkersAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Object,Void> {

    private InsertMarkersAsyncTask() {
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        List<Site> sites = SiteDatabase.getInstance(getContext()).siteDAO().loadSites();
        LatLng current;
        for (int i = 0; i < sites.size()-1; i++) {
            String[] siteLatLng = String.valueOf(sites.get(i).getLatlng()).split(",");
            Double[] doubleLatLng = new Double[2];
            doubleLatLng[0] = Double.parseDouble(siteLatLng[0]);
            doubleLatLng[1] = Double.parseDouble(siteLatLng[1]);
            current = new LatLng(doubleLatLng[0], doubleLatLng[1]);
            publishProgress(sites.get(i), current);
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Object... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

        Site site = (Site) values[0];
        LatLng current = (LatLng) values[1];
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(current).title(site.getSiteName()));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {

        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I get some feedback on the down vote? I'm no expert at android, but this worked for me... Should I have put the solution in my question?

Comment: haha, No worries, this code above is just for testing. The site should force the user to comment after a down vote. Maybe I'll learn something!